# symfony 3 add confirmation box to delete

Tags: php, html, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have a list with users from a db which has a working delete button.
Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{  
    /**
     * @Route("/homepage", name="homepage")
     */
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {
        $users = new Users();
        $userssrc = null;
        $name = null;
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $defaultData = array('message' => 'wut');
        $formsearch = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
                 ->add('search', TextType::class, array('label'=>'Suche', 'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style'=>'margin-bottom:0.5cm; width:50%;'))) 
                 ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'suchen','attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')))
                 ->add('reset', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'zurücksetzten', 'attr'=>  array('class'=>'btn btn-default')))
                 ->getForm();
         $formsearch->handleRequest($request);
         if($formsearch->isSubmitted() && $formsearch->isValid()){
            $name = $formsearch['search']->getData();
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT u 
                 FROM AppBundle:Users u
                 WHERE u.vorname = :name
                 OR u.nachname = :name')->setParameter('name', $name);
            $userssrc = $query->getResult();

            if ($formsearch->get('reset')->isClicked()){
                return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
            }

         }
        else{
            $vae = 'no form submission';
            dump($vae);
        }
        //gets the table entries
        $list = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')
                ->findAll();
        // Returns to index.html.twig with the variable liste, in which the db entries are
        return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', array('list'=>$list, 'form'=>$formsearch->createView(), 'userssrc'=>$userssrc)); 
        //return $this->render('base.html.twig', array('session'=>$session));
    }}
```

and here's the index.html.twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Personeneinträge{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class='container'>
<h1>Personeneinträge</h1>
<form class='form-inline' method="post">
{{ form_start(form)}}
{{ form_widget(form)}}
{{ form_end(form)}}
</form>
<table class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
     <th>Vorname</th>
     <th>Nachname</th>
     <th>Strasse</th>
     <th>Ort</th>
     <th>PLZ</th>
         <th>Beschreibung</th>
         <th class='col-md-3'>Bild</th>
         <th>&nbsp;</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
    {% if userssrc is null %}
        {% for row in list %}
     <tr>
             <td>{{row.vorname}}</td>
             <td>{{row.nachname}}</td>
             <td>{{row.strasse}}</td>
             <td>{{row.ort}}</td>
             <td>{{row.plz}}</td>
             <td>{{row.beschreibung}}</td>
             {% if row.bild %}
             <td><img class='usrimg' src="{{asset(row.bild, 'uploaded_files')}}" alt="Bild zum Benutzer"></td>
             {% else %}
             <td>-</td>
             {% endif %}
             <td>
                 <a href="{{ path('details',{'id':row.id})}}" class="btn btn-success">Details</a> 
                 <a href="{{ path('edit',{'id':row.id})}}" class="btn btn-info">Bearbeiten</a> 
                 <a href="{{ path('delete',{'id':row.id})}}" class="btn btn-danger">Löschen</a>
                 <a href="{{ path('mail',{'id':row.id})}}" class="btn btn-default">Als Mail senden</a>  
             </td>
        </tr> 
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for row in userssrc %}
        <tr>
             <td>{{row.vorname}}</td>
             <td>{{row.nachname}}</td>
             <td>{{row.strasse}}</td>
             <td>{{row.ort}}</td>
             <td>{{row.plz}}</td>
             <td>{{row.beschreibung}}</td>
             <td>
                 <a href="{{ path('details',{'id':row.id})}}" class="btn btn-success">Details</a> 
                 <a href="{{ path('edit',{'id':row.id})}}" class="btn btn-info">Bearbeiten</a> 
                 <a href="{{ path('delete',{'id':row.id})}}" class="btn btn-danger">Löschen</a>        
             </td>
        </tr> 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
     </tbody>
</table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I now want it to ask for a confirmation before it deletes the entry, does anyone know a simple solution?
Just in case it helps to understand, here's a screenshot of the rendered view:
[image]

I'm sorry, forgot to add my deleteAction:

```
/**
     * @Route("/loeschen/{id}", name="delete")
     */
     public function deleteAction($id){
        //start Doctrine
             $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
             $list = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')->find($id);
             return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage', array('remove'));   
             $em->remove($list);
             $em->flush();

     }
```

Comment: You can use a [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) with javascript

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you like. Some common methods;

- Create an intermediary page with just a button when deleting as confirmation (Are you sure?). Some of symfony's generators use this 'DeleteForm' type of thing. Where it links to a new page with the ID using the route, and on POST it actually deletes.
- You can add an [unmapped](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) [checkbox](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html) which would not attempt to save it on the object. Just check if it is checked in the controller. (although that doesn't really fit your list layout)
- And there is javascript;

  - Simple [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)
  - Fancy [dialog/modal/popup](https://www.google.com/search?q=confirmation+dialog+modal+popup) thingies.
  - Multiple state buttons (pressing once changes it to inform the user are you sure, then again to actually do it or whatever).

And im sure there are other options too.

Comment: those are nice ways of doing it thanks, but has no one an example or something like it? Having problems integrating js in my project and letting it return a var^^"